# How to access Firebase Database APIs?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So in firebase I created a database named `crud`.

[image]

Now database rules looks like this,

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Now I try to access the API with `https://crud-12b8c.firebaseio.com/crud/users.json` then I get `404 not found` error. What am I doing wrong here? I am new to Firebase btw.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up Cloud Firestore and the Firebase Realtime Database. `firebaseio.com` URLs are for Realtime Databases, but the console screenshot you're showing and the security rules you're displaying are for Firestore.

I'd recommend reading [the guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) about how to access data using the Firestore SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MichaelBleigh. The thing is I don't wanna use SDKs. Can't I access the API directly?

Comment: To access Firestore without an SDK you can use its REST API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the firebase API is done through the Rest API service of which, you can find the full documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest

This includes means of accessing Firestore data points directly through web requests:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/get

For example:

- https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/crud-12b8c/databases/(default)/documents/crud

It does get complicated but this is a great start to using Firebase per your needs.